# RavenDB Client 3.0 with casting error

Tags: c#, ravendb, nosql

I just upgraded the RavenDB Client via NuGet to 3.0 and my server to 2.5.0 and now I got this casting error in the most simple code.
I am fetching data from the db by id `var result = session.Load<Chart>(chartId);` 
The error is

> Unable to cast object of type 'Raven.Json.Linq.RavenJArray' to type 'Raven.Json.Linq.RavenJObject

The error is not int the query object at least I havent come accross it, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a 3.0 client to talk to a 2.x server, that is not supported.